# Onde encontro os registros como login e senha guardados no xml que o SharedPreference faz?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Eu queria encontrar o caminho do arquivo, porque quero confirmar se minha função encriptografou esses dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente, está localizado em `/data/data/com.pacote.do.seu.app/shared_prefs/nome_da_pref.xml`.

Você precisa de [root](http://olhardigital.uol.com.br/noticia/root-para-android-saiba-o-que-e-e-como-fazer/40421) para acessar este arquivo ou usar uma função para ler e mostrar o conteúdo direto do seu aplicativo, já que só ele e o superusuário têm permissão para isto.

Comment: Esse data é um caminho invisível no desktop?

Comment: Eu gostaria de visualizar pelo Desktop...

Comment: Ela está no Android, você precisa olhar direto nele. Mas se você usa um emulador de Android, pode tentar o seguinte comando dentro pasta **platform-tools** do seu Android SDK: `adb shell cat /data/data/com.pacote.do.seu.app/shared_prefs/nome_da_pref.xml`

Comment: Está no meu android? Onde  fica esse caminho então no android? pf me ajude...

Comment: É que eu preciso confirmaar se ele escriptografou o login e senha digitados pelo usuário...

Comment: Caso esteja usando um smartphone Android, você precisa de acesso _root_ e um explorador de arquivos com suporte a _root_ para acessar a pasta. A localização dela está acima, na resposta principal.

Comment: Entendido. amanhã tentarei isso. vou baixar esse explorador de arquivos. obrigada